# Count all 0 and negative 0 in a row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to count the value **0** in this table, including the negative **-0** in Excel formula using `countif`

The logic I'm aiming for is, *Count all 0s **and** all negative 0s in this row*.

Expected Result: **2**

Actual Result: **1**

| Product | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| Item A | 10 |
| Item B | **0** |
| Item C | **-0.001** |
| Item D | -10 |

What I tried so far.

```
=Countif(ROWS, "=0") // count all 0s
=Countif(ROWS, "=0" & "<0.*") // count all 0 and 0s with decimal using wildcard
=Countif(ROWS, ">=0") //count all 0 and less than 0 (which makes no total sense)
=countif(ROWS, "=0!<1") //count all 0 but not less than negative 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,"<=0",B2:B5,">-1")
```

[image]